# Adding the polynomials (bytes) in the ring $Z_2 [x]/(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)=GF(2^8)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring

I need to solve few similar exercises. One of them is:

Add the polynomials (bytes) in the ring $Z_2 [x]/(x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1)=GF(2^8)$

a) ‘57’+’02’

b) ‘03’+’03’

c)  ‘FF’+’0F’

I try to learn it by myself. I bought a book with some exercises and solutions, but I can't find anything similar to that. I searched whole YouTube, and check other topics on this site. I'm not asking to solve this one, but maybe someone can send a link to similar exercises and tutorials on how it supposed to be solved? Or can write what are the steps to do so on other examples?

Thank you for any hints in that matter!

UPDATE:
I think I understood how to calculate it. I was lookin through the Internet with wrong keywords. I calculated each answer. Could someone tell me is it right?

a) $001010101, x^6+x^4+x^2+1$

b) $0$

c) $11110000, x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4$

Comment: Would you be able to add the polynomials if the ring were $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ rather than the quotient you have there?

Comment: I can add polynomials, but I don't understand what it means to add them in the ring, especially when they are bytes (I understand that I need to convert all numbers from a), b) and c) to a binary system, but what next?).

Comment: Speaking computer-sciencishly, addition here should be nothing but XOR.

Comment: @Lubin Yep, that I understood. I also get that when we have Z2[x] we need to reduce all of the answers with 2 in polymonials (e.g. 2, 2x), alike we will have Z4[x] then we will reduce all x with 4 (for example 4x). Last thing that I don't understand is the information from the instruction that we have Z2[x]/(x8+x4+x3+x+1) - it feels redundant right now for me, why we need to care that it's x8+x4+x3+x+1? What to do with this information? My solutions are now also added to the main question.

Comment: You need any $\Bbb Z_2$-irreducible polynomial of degree eight, of which there are thirty, I believe. This one was chosen as, perhaps, having fewest nonzero coefficients.

Comment: @Lubin but does it change anything with the solutions? Or the job is only to perform XOR or add polymonials and reduce some solutions (e.g. 2 with Z2[x] etc.)? Or is there another step? (EDIT: And I would like to thank you for your responses and time :). I just visited your profile, and I really appreciate all your help, Sir. Have a nice day :).

Comment: Well, I’m not sure what the problem is. Addition is simplicity itself, via XOR. It’s multiplication that will present the difficulties.

Comment: Your answer a) is off simply by having nine digits instead of eight. Should be only one zero on the left.

Comment: @Lubin You said that multiplication should be more difficult. Won't it simply be logical AND in this particular case?

Comment: Hardly: $x$ times $x^7$ is $x^4+x^3+x+1$, I guess that’s $10000000\times00000001=00011011$.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

The field has 256 elements and are all of the form $\sum_{i=0}^7 a_ix^i$.

Addition is easy as in the usual polynomial ring and is done component-wise:

$\sum_{i=0}^7 a_ix^i + b\sum_{i=0}^7 a_ix^i = \sum_{i=0}^7 (a_i+b_i)x^i$

where the coefficients $a_i,b_i$ are added modulo 2.

---

‘57’+’02’ or in binary '00101111 + 00000010'

Here $a(x) = x^5+x^3+x^2+x+1$ and $b(x)=x$.

So the addition yields '00101101' or

$a(x)+b(x) = x^5+x^3+x+1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort. I understand why the field is 256 (because of 2^8 in GF), but I can't understand later statements. How you know that 00101111 is a(x)=x5+x3+x2+x+1 and 00000010 is simply b(x) = x. How it is calculated? Can we really solve this only by changing digits to the binary representations and then just performing logic AND (conjunction) on them (that's how you get 00101101)? I'm sorry if I'm taking your time, but I really appreciated the fact that you've tried to help :). I'm biologist by education and unfortunately those things are not trivial for me.

Comment: Update of my comment: OK, I have all of the steps and I get how to calculate that kind of tasks (I will write about it later for anyone in the future that would have same problem), but still there is something that I don't understand in your answer. 57(16) is 1010111 not 101111, but this is probably only a typo. But then when you have your result as a 00101101 wasn't it supposed to be x^5+x^3+x^2+1 instead of x^5 + x^3 + x + 1 - is it also a typo or I don't understand something?